# How do I move a USB Time Machine backup to a Time Capsule?

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

Is there a safe way to move a Time Machine backup on an external USB hard drive to a Time Capsule?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's straightforward to do it, even though it would take quite sometime to complete depending on the size of your current backups. Follow the detailed procedure at [Copy  Local  backups to be used on a  NETWORK](http://pondini.org/TM/18.html#id18).

Here's a summary of what's required and the steps.

The backups go into a sparsebundle on a `Time Capsule`. So you need to create that sparsebundle on the `Time Capsule`, mount it in `Finder` and then copy over everything from your USB drive into the mounted volume.

Here are the basic steps with some additional information:

1. Configure `Time Machine` to back up to the `Time Capsule` and start a backup. This will make it create the sparsebundle.
2. Cancel the backup once the copying starts (as seen in the progress window).
3. Mount the `Time Machine Backups` sparsebundle in `Finder` by double-clicking it (or using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>)
4. Delete the `Backups.backupdb` folder inside this volume (you'll be replacing it with the backup you already have).
5. Open your current `Time Machine` backup USB drive in `Finder` and copy the `Backups.backupdb` folder from it to the `Time Machine Backups` partition (mounted from the `Time Capsule`).
6. Enter your administrator password and accept the prompts (this may happen a couple of times).

Comment: This would appear to no longer work in El Capitan as the sparsebundle mounts as read only.

Comment: I'm on El Cap and I didn't have that problem. I would suggest however after step 2 to turn Time Machine off so it doesn't try to backup to the time capsule while you are also manually copying.