# Move Time Machine from case-sensitive USB disk to case-insensitive Airport Time Capsule

Tags: macos, time-machine, filesystem, time-capsule

My wife's MacBook has a case-sensitive Time Machine backup (her backup is stored on a case-sensitive file system). Our Time Capsule is not case-sensitive.

How can I migrate her Time Machine history from the case-sensitive USB disk to the Time Capsule, without losing the already existing Time Machine backups on the same Time Capsule?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move a USB Time Machine backup to a Time Capsule?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104277/how-do-i-move-a-usb-time-machine-backup-to-a-time-capsule)

Comment: It is not a duplicate as this question specifies case sensitivity and hence is more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the approach from [#104277](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104277/how-do-i-move-a-usb-time-machine-backup-to-a-time-capsule), and it worked.

Apparently Time Machine doesn't care about the file system case sensitivity when copying Time Machine backups from a local USB disk to a networked Time Capsule disk. The only thing that matters, is having Time Machine first create the Sparse Bundle on the Time Capsule.

In other words, the instructions from #104277 can be followed, even in case the Time Machine backup originated from a case-sensitive file system.

I however can't rule out that it worked only because there were no case insensitive file/folder name collisions in the first place (e.g., no distinct files named 'file', 'File' and 'FILE' in the same origin folder).